# Is there a bijective function $f: \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a bijective function $f: \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$? If it exists, then example. If not, then proof?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is uncountable, while $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so there cannot be such a bijection. (If $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ were countable, then $\Bbb R$ would be the union of the countable sets $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, but the union of two countable sets is countable, and $\Bbb R$ is not countable.)

Answer (score 4):

The reals are uncountable and the rationals are countable.  What would this mean if there were one?